# How to make mobile responsive vertical range slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have done a range slider position into vertical. but it's not responsive. I'm checked in chrome default mobile devices. when adjusting the range slider it will scroll the page

I have added my code here.

```css
.slido{   
 -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.slido::-webkit-slider-thumb {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" class="slido" min="1" max="100" step="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Using just `transform` on an element does not affect the size or position of its parent or of any other elements, at all. There is absolutely no way to change this fact of how transform works. so adding the `div` on parent level (which can handle the overflow of rotation) is one solution.

**code Updated:**

```css
.slido {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.slido::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rotation-wrapper-outer {
  display: table;
}

.rotation-wrapper-inner {
  padding: 50% 0;
  height: 0;
}

.element-to-rotate {
  display: block;
  transform-origin: top left;
  /* Note: for a CLOCKWISE rotation, use the commented-out
         transform instead of this one. */
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%);
  /* transform: rotate(90deg) translate(0, -100%); */
  margin-top: -50%;
  /* Not vital, but possibly a good idea if the element you're rotating contains
         text and you want a single long vertical line of text and the pre-rotation
         width of your element is small enough that the text wraps: */
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="rotation-wrapper-outer">
    <div class="rotation-wrapper-inner">
      <input type="range" class="slido" min="1" max="100" step="1">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Width `width: 100%;`? % of what? Why don't you rather use `vh` unit? Width at 80vh, will always be relative to the device viewport height.

Comment: After your edit - You forgot that the element is rotated. And PS why do you use `display: table;`

Comment: Updated please check.

Comment: for the responsive thing. there will be no effect to height as the parent divs are available too. to make adjustment based on different devices he can use media-queries.

Comment: To prevent the page from scrolling when you use the scrollbar add `touch-action: none;` to the input and/or container.

Answer (score 0):

Okay there is 3 solutions I know off.

1. Rotate the input itself not the parent div, this might work but now you might have issues as the div parent div will not have rotated.
2. Apply `touch-none` to the input. This prevents the browser from wanting to default to scroll when you touch the slider thumb.
3. Apply a `transform: scaleX(1);`, I don't know why this works but 2 + 3 is what I had to do to make it work vertically.

Answer (score -2):

You have transform the horizontal slider in to vertical which won't work so you can use vertical slider only check snippet.

```js
let app = (() => {

  function updateSlider(element) {
    if (element) {
      let parent = element.parentElement,
        lastValue = parent.getAttribute('data-slider-value');

      if (lastValue === element.value) {
        return; // No value change, no need to update then
      }

      parent.setAttribute('data-slider-value', element.value);
      let $thumb = parent.querySelector('.range-slider__thumb'),
        $bar = parent.querySelector('.range-slider__bar'),
        pct = element.value * ((parent.clientHeight - $thumb.clientHeight) / parent.clientHeight);

      $thumb.style.bottom = `${pct}%`;
      $bar.style.height = `calc(${pct}% + ${$thumb.clientHeight/2}px)`;
      $thumb.textContent = `${element.value}%`;
    }
  }
  return {
    updateSlider: updateSlider
  };

})();

(function initAndSetupTheSliders() {
  const inputs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.range-slider input'));
  inputs.forEach(input => input.setAttribute('value', '50'));
  inputs.forEach(input => app.updateSlider(input));
  // Cross-browser support where value changes instantly as you drag the handle, therefore two event types.
  inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('input', element => app.updateSlider(input)));
  inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', element => app.updateSlider(input)));
})();
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #3D3D4A;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.range-slider {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.range-slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2em;
  left: 0.5em;
  content: attr(data-slider-value) '%';
  color: white;
  font-size: 90%;
}

.range-slider__thumb {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: white;
  color: #777;
  font-size: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #3D3D4A;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.range-slider__bar {
  left: 16px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(dodgerblue, blue);
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 8px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.range-slider input[type=range][orient=vertical] {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  writing-mode: bt-lr;
  -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
}

.range-slider input[type=range][orient=vertical]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track,
.range-slider input[type=range][orient=vertical]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.range-slider input[type=range][orient=vertical]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  border: none;
  background: #343440;
  width: 8px;
  border-color: #343440;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #3D3D4A;
}

.range-slider input[type=range][orient=vertical]::-moz-range-track {
  border: none;
  background: #343440;
  width: 8px;
  border-color: #343440;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #3D3D4A;
}

.range-slider input[type=range][orient=vertical]::-ms-track {
  border: none;
  background: #343440;
  width: 8px;
  border-color: #343440;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #3D3D4A;
  color: transparent;
  height: 100%;
}

.range-slider input[type=range][orient=vertical]::-ms-fill-lower,
.range-slider input[type=range][orient=vertical]::-ms-fill-upper,
.range-slider input[type=range][orient=vertical]::-ms-tooltip {
  display: none;
}

.range-slider input[type=range][orient=vertical]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.range-slider input[type=range][orient=vertical]::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.range-slider input[type=range][orient=vertical]::-ms-thumb {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="range-slider">
    <input type="range" orient="vertical" min="0" max="100" />
    <div class="range-slider__bar"></div>
    <div class="range-slider__thumb"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan This is not copy pasted check vertical slider it is based on screen resolution. its enhanced version of one of the code pen as per request.

Comment: So you enhanced someones else code. What was the enhancement? Mind explaining the enhancement? What are the changes? What's better now? How that code relates to OP's code? PS: As per requested? By whom? Code pen? What?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan enhancement related to the height == height: calc(100vh - 50px); === better in sense based on screen resolution it will adjust the height. and as request "teenage vampire" without scrolling page you will be able to see entire range slider.

Comment: i think we can solve this issue without adding that library.! please check my answer.